# DOM table from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, dom, html-table

Need help How to add custom columns to a table, for example, the first column needs to be an ID after the column DIED I need to add column age. I try to add a column named Age in the middle of the table, but the glade is shifted and this field displays the information that should be displayed in the Father column.
The table is dynamically generated from JSON without using innerHTML.

```js
const ANCESTRY_FILE = [
  {
    name: "Carolus Haverbeke",
    sex: "m",
    born: 1832,
    died: 1905,
    father: "Carel Haverbeke",
    mother: "Maria van Brussel"
  },
  {
    name: "Emma de Milliano",
    sex: "f",
    born: 1876,
    died: 1956,
    father: "Petrus de Milliano",
    mother: "Sophia van Damme"
  },
  {
    name: "Maria de Rycke",
    sex: "f",
    born: 1683,
    died: 1724,
    father: "Frederik de Rycke",
    mother: "Laurentia van Vlaenderen"
  }
];

function showPeople(element, people) {
  element = document.querySelector(".people");
  let table = document.createElement("table");
  table.className = "people__table";
  let thead = document.createElement("thead");
  let tbody = document.createElement("tbody");

  function addThead(table, keys) {
    let tr = document.createElement("tr");

    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      let td = document.createElement("td");
      td.textContent = `${keys[i]}`;
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    thead.appendChild(tr);
    table.appendChild(thead);
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    let child = people[i];
    if (i === 0) {
      addThead(table, Object.keys(child));
    }
    let tr = document.createElement("tr");
    tr.className = "person";
    Object.keys(child).forEach(function(elem) {
      let td = document.createElement("td");
      td.textContent = `${child[elem]}`;
      tr.appendChild(td);
    });
    table.appendChild(tbody);
    tbody.appendChild(tr);
  }

  element.appendChild(table);
}

showPeople("element", ANCESTRY_FILE);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="people"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a fun approach using map and templating.
Note the we use an `Array.map` function to transform our JSON and add the ID and Age data to the objects before we build the table.

I don't know what you want ID to be but you can fix that.

```js
const ANCESTRY_FILE = [{
    name: "Carolus Haverbeke",
    sex: "m",
    born: 1832,
    died: 1905,
    father: "Carel Haverbeke",
    mother: "Maria van Brussel"
  },
  {
    name: "Emma de Milliano",
    sex: "f",
    born: 1876,
    died: 1956,
    father: "Petrus de Milliano",
    mother: "Sophia van Damme"
  },
  {
    name: "Maria de Rycke",
    sex: "f",
    born: 1683,
    died: 1724,
    father: "Frederik de Rycke",
    mother: "Laurentia van Vlaenderen"
  }
];

const buildHeader = (data) => Object.keys(data).map(k => `<th>${k}</th>`).join('');
const buildRow = (data) => Object.keys(data).map(k => `<td>${data[k]}</td>`).join('');

function showPeople(people) {
  let element = document.querySelector(".people");
  let table = document.createElement("table");
  table.classList.add("people__table");
  let thead = document.createElement("thead");
  thead.innerHTML = `<tr>${buildHeader(people[0])}</tr>`;
  table.appendChild(thead);
  let tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
  tbody.innerHTML = people.map(p => `<tr>${buildRow(p)}</tr>`).join('');
  table.appendChild(tbody);
  element.appendChild(table);
}

// Function to add the custom data first.
const customPeople = (data) => data.map((p,i) => {
  return {
    id: i, // Default the ID field to be index for now.
    name: p.name,
    sex: p.sex,
    born: p.born,
    died: p.died,
    age: p.died - p.born, // Compute our age field
    father: p.father,
    mother: p.mother
  };
});

// Note we call to transform our data before building table.
showPeople(customPeople(ANCESTRY_FILE));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>repl.it</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="people"></div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```